# Formbuilder : Entities passed to the choice field must be managed

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

i am trying to build a quizz with 3 entities :
Quizz, Question and QuestionAnswer.

Quizz embed a collection of Question which i need to display with all possible answers.

here are my form builders:

QuizzType :

```
        $builder->add('questions', 'collection', array('type' => new QuestionType(),'options' => array('label' => false)));
```

QuestionType:

```
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $this->currentQuestion = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->add('answers', 'entity', array(
            'label' => $this->currentQuestion->getValue(),
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'property' =>'value',
            'class' => 'MyQuizzBundle:QuestionAnswer',//*/
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                $tmp = $er->createQueryBuilder("a")
                    ->where("a.question = 1");
                return $tmp;
            },
        ));
    });
```

Quizz:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="quizz")
 */
private $questions;
```

Question:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuestionAnswer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $answers;
```

QuestionAnswer:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $question;
```

I got the following error

```
Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?
```

I've been trying to find a sollution for hours, i saw people solved this problem because there were mistakes in there entity annotations but i can't find any error here.

UPDATE: Here is how i instantiate my form:

```
$quizz = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("MyQuizzBundle:Quizz")->find(1);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($quizz);
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuizzType(), $quizz);
```

after some testing i tried to not instantiate the quizz but just one question with it's answers, i still get the error:

```
$question = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("QuizzBundle:Question")->find(1);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($question);
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuestionType(), $question);
```

The error is thrown only when i try to display the field as a radio button (with expanded = true and multiple = false).
I have no error if i display it as a checkbox or select.

Is it a known bug or am i doing something wrong ?

UPDATE 2:
looks like i can display it as a radio if i set the 'mapped' attribute to false :

```
$form->add('answers', 'entity', array(
        'label' => $this->currentQuestion->getValue(),
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        'property' =>'value',
        'mapped' => false, 
        'class' => 'MyQuizzBundle:QuestionAnswer',//*/
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            $tmp = $er->createQueryBuilder("a")
                ->where("a.question = 1");
            return $tmp;
        },
    ));
```

obviously i would like to avoid using 'mapped' => false, so i can use the value in my controller after the user submit it the form.

Comment: how you create form?

Comment: i just updated my answer

Comment: i added more explanation at the end of the post